# Say, I got Ubuntu offline repo. What else?

Tags: repository

I need Ubuntu repositories for offline use. I know how to do it, so it is ok.

My question is: will I need some additional software?

Example: Nvidia / Cuda drivers, or whatever other drivers - are they all in the Ubuntu repo, or are they somewhere else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Nvidia drivers are in the `restricted` repositories.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nvidia-driver-470

Comment: Thank you. 
So if I download just Ubuntu repository, I wouldn't need
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads ?
This is great.

Comment: @SteveBrown The ones in the Ubuntu repos probably are not as up-to-date, but yes, I use these `restricted` ones in my local mirror: `focal restricted`, `focal-security restricted`, and `focal-updates restricted`.

Comment: Great! Thanks :)